# How to add the close button in SP.UI.Status

Tags: 2010, web-part, javascript, form, error-handling

I use status bar to show exception message in code-behind. I wanna add a close button in the status bar for user, so they can remove the bar. Here is my code:

```
        protected virtual void ShowNotifyException(Severity severity, string errorMessage)
    {
        string statusBar = @"
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){{
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(
                function(){{
                    this.statusID = SP.UI.Status.addStatus(""{0}"", ""<p><span style='float: left'>{1}</span><span style='float: right'><input type='button' name='cancelStatusBar' value='X' onclick='SP.UI.Status.removeStatus(this.statusID);'/></span></p>"");
                    SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(this.statusID, ""{2}"");
                }},
            'core.js'
            )}},
        'sp.js'
        );";

        string color = "";
        string title = "";
        if (severity.Equals(Severity.Error))
        {
            color = "red";
            title = EMC.Documentum.SharePoint.Core.ResourceManagement.ResourceManager.GetLocalString("StatusBarTitle_Error");
        }
        else if (severity.Equals(Severity.Warn))
        {
            color = "yellow";
            title = EMC.Documentum.SharePoint.Core.ResourceManagement.ResourceManager.GetLocalString("StatusBarTitle_Warn");
        }
        else if (severity.Equals(Severity.Info))
        {
            color = "blue";
            title = EMC.Documentum.SharePoint.Core.ResourceManagement.ResourceManager.GetLocalString("StatusBarTitle_Info");
        }
        else 
        {
            color = "green";
        }
        string script = string.Format(statusBar, title, errorMessage, color);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(), "ShowErrorMessage", script, true);
    }
```

The question is, 1. the button is displayed correctly, but it doesn't work. 2. Except add button, is there any other way to implement my requirement?

Comment: I don't wanna add timeout for the status bar, because our requirement is to remove status bar from a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I separate the JS to a standalone file, and include a function:

```
var statusID='';
var addStatusBar = function(title, message, color){
var messageHtml = '<p><span style="float: left"><b>' + title + '</b>' + message + '</span><span style="float: right" id="close_button_span"></span></p>';
statusID = SP.UI.Status.addStatus(messageHtml);
SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(statusID, color);
var close_button = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("close");
close_button.appendChild(linkText);
close_button.name = 'status_close_button';
close_button.href = "#";
close_button.onclick = function(){
    SP.UI.Status.removeStatus(statusID);
    statusID = '';
}
var statusBar = document.getElementById('close_button_span');
statusBar.appendChild(close_button);};
```

Then register the js file in CreateChildControls with ScriptLink control, and use below statement to call the js function:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(), "ShowErrorMessage", "ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {{addStatusBar('Error: ', 'message', 'red')}}, 'sp.js');", true);
```

The button in status bar will be worked.